# Auto-generation of new columns based on existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, automation, transform

I want to create new columns based on the other columns in a pandas dataframe with some logic to it. For each column that has the name *[string] > Full Name*, I want to generate two new columns called *[string] > Asset Type* and *[string] > Domain*. There are also column that do not have this *[string] > Full Name* structure, and those needs to be untouched.

Here is what I have:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'recipient > Full Name': {0: 'Norway', 1: 'Sweden'},
                    'transporter > Full Name': {0: "UPS", 1: "Sweden Mail Services"},
                    'Description': {0:'Priority mail', 1: 'Fragile object - be careful'}})
```

And here is what I want:

```
wantedData = pd.DataFrame({'recipient > Full Name': {0: 'Norway', 1: 'Sweden'},
                    'transporter > Full Name': {0: "UPS", 1: "Sweden Mail Services"},
                    'Description': {0:'Priority mail', 1: 'Fragile object - be careful'},
                    'recipient > Asset Type': {0: "Country", 1: "Country"},
                    'recipient > Domain': {0: "Transport", 1: "Transport"},
                    'transporter > Asset Type': {0: "Legal Enitity", 1: "Legal Entity"},
                    'transporter > Domain': {0: "Transport", 1: "Transport"}})
```

Also, all the *Domain* columns have the same value for all rows, is there a way to autopopulate it with "Transport" which is the example I used in the code?

I have tried creating some code that looks at column 0 and creates column 1 and 2 based on column 0 - and iterates over all columns, but this messes with the columns that I want to keep untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'recipient > Full Name': {0: 'Norway', 1: 'Sweden'},
                'transporter > Full Name': {0: "UPS", 1: "Sweden Mail Services"},
                'Description': {0:'Priority mail', 1: 'Fragile object - be careful'}})

# value_dict contains initial values for new columns (except those ending with Domain) 
value_dict = {
    'recipient > Asset Type' : 'Country',
    'transporter > Asset Type' : 'Legal Entity'
}

# key_list contains combination of new columns - in this case we want to create 
# 2 new columns (... Asset Type, ... Domain) for each column containing '>' 
key_list = ['Asset Type', 'Domain']

# iterate through list of column names containing '>' (other columns remain untouched)
for col in [col for col in data.columns if '>' in col]:
    # and for each such column create 2 new columns with new names (could be more or less...depends on key_list)
    for i in range(len(key_list)):
        new_colname = '{} > {}'.format(col.split(' >')[0], key_list[i%len(key_list)])
        # set Transport as value if column ends with '> Domain' or value from value_dict or None if not specified
        new_value = 'Transport' if new_colname.endswith('> Domain') else value_dict[new_colname] if new_colname in value_dict else None 
        data[new_colname] = new_value
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello I tried something similar to this but get the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'columns'. The problem seems to be with data.columns after for col in ...